# counting the occurrences of a specific label in a sliding window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the below DataFrame.

```
         t_msec    ID
0           1.1  0200
1           1.4  020a
2           8.9  01f4
3          11.1  0200
4          13.2  02e2
...         ...   ...
85454  189915.3  02e4
85455  189915.6  02e6
85456  189921.8  0200
85457  189922.3  01f4
85458  189924.0  020a
```

I want to run a sliding window that counts the occurrences of a specific label 1 second ahead.

```
only_id_df = df[df.ID == id]
counts = Counter()
for index, row in only_id_df.iterrows():
    mask = (only_id_df.t_msec< row.t_msec + 1000) & (only_id_df.t_msec> row.t_msec)
    counts.update([len(only_id_df[mask])])
```

However, this is very slow and I know there must be a way to perform it without manually iterating each line and filtering (which I know is inefficient).

What is the proper way of achieving this goal? how can I speed this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

For my test I used the following DataFrame:

```
   t_msec    ID
0      60  0200
1      70  020a
2     445  01f4
3     555  0200
4     660  02e2
5    1005  0200
6    1510  02e2
7    2105  0200
8    2260  02e2
```

So if we look for e.g. *ID == '0200'*, within *1 s* from the initial row
(*t_msec == 60*) forward, then there are **3** rows, on
*t_msec == [ 60, 555, 1005 ]*.

To compute the whole result we must perform a few tricks:

1. In order to perform **rolling** calculations based on a Time Series,
   we must calculate a temporary column, involving *pd.to_datetime* and
   set it as the index.
2. But rolling calculations are performed **backwards** from the
   current row, i.e. *Pandas* looks for rows between e.g. *1 s* **before**
   the current index and **now** (the current index) and performs the
   defined calculation on rows within this window, whereas we want a
   **forward** looking window.
   So the trick needed here is to:

   - compute the index as *df.t_msec.max() - df.t_msec [ms]*,
   - process it in reverse order,
   - reverse the order of the result again.
3. The reason for the last trick is that:

   - we want to look at *ID* column (a **string**),
   - but rolling calculations can be performed only on **numeric** columns.
4. Fortunately, *ID* column contain only **hex** strings, which can be
   converted to *int*. So we convert it and save under a new (temporary) column.

The first step is to perform "setup" calculations:

```
lbl = int('0200', 16)  # Label to look for (hex -> dec)
# ID converted to dec
df['ID_dec'] = df.ID.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
# Set index
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.t_msec.max() - df.t_msec, unit='ms'))
```

so that *df* contains now:

```
                         t_msec    ID  ID_dec
t_msec                                       
1970-01-01 00:00:02.200      60  0200     512
1970-01-01 00:00:02.190      70  020a     522
1970-01-01 00:00:01.815     445  01f4     500
1970-01-01 00:00:01.705     555  0200     512
1970-01-01 00:00:01.600     660  02e2     738
1970-01-01 00:00:01.255    1005  0200     512
1970-01-01 00:00:00.750    1510  02e2     738
1970-01-01 00:00:00.155    2105  0200     512
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000    2260  02e2     738
```

The second (main) step is to calculate *Nr* column:

```
df['Nr'] = df.ID_dec[::-1].rolling(window=pd.offsets.Second(1), closed='both')\
    .apply(lambda grp: grp[grp == lbl].size, raw=False).astype(int)[::-1]
```

Note both *[::-1]* reversing the source column and the result itself.

Now *df* contains:

```
                         t_msec    ID  ID_dec  Nr
t_msec                                           
1970-01-01 00:00:02.200      60  0200     512   3
1970-01-01 00:00:02.190      70  020a     522   2
1970-01-01 00:00:01.815     445  01f4     500   2
1970-01-01 00:00:01.705     555  0200     512   2
1970-01-01 00:00:01.600     660  02e2     738   1
1970-01-01 00:00:01.255    1005  0200     512   1
1970-01-01 00:00:00.750    1510  02e2     738   1
1970-01-01 00:00:00.155    2105  0200     512   1
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000    2260  02e2     738   0
```

And the final step is to drop temporary columns and restore
the original index:

```
df = df.drop(columns='ID_dec').reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final result is:

```
   t_msec    ID  Nr
0      60  0200   3
1      70  020a   2
2     445  01f4   2
3     555  0200   2
4     660  02e2   1
5    1005  0200   1
6    1510  02e2   1
7    2105  0200   1
8    2260  02e2   0
```

The execution time should be considerably shorter. Write a comment about the execution time of your code and mine (+ the row number).